# Where should i put icons for TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a multiplatform (Android/iOS) Xamarin.Forms app.

I have put a TabbedPage. I want to define an Icon for each page. I have tried do set Icon Propery in XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="XXXX.YYYY">
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <ContentPage Title="Recherche" Icon="search.png">
```

I have an error in Xamarin preview and a blank app when i try it in iOS simulator.

My question is: Where should i put search.png file?

In shared project?
In a particular subfolder?

In each iOS/Android subproject?

Answer (score 9):

The image assets need to be on each platform specific project so that they are correctly sized, named and formatted for each OS.

Read this article to get a better understanding about images: [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

> **iOS** - Place images in the Resources folder with Build Action:
>   BundleResource. Retina versions of the image should also be supplied
>   - two and three times the resolution with a @2x or @3x suffixes on the filename before the file extension (eg. myimage@2x.png).
>
> **Android** -
>   Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action:
>   AndroidResource. High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be
>   supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as
>   drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).
>
> **Windows Phone** -
>   Place images in the application's root directory with Build Action:
>   Content.
>
> **Windows/UWP** - Place images in the application's root
>   directory with Build Action: Content.

After you have correctly placed the images, you can properly use them with for example `Icon="search.png"`.

Comment: I was placing my images on the .xcassets, and my icons were not appearing. When I placed them on the Resources folder, they started to appear normally. Only an advice to not struggle asking yourself where the error is if you are putting the images on .xcassets.